# FATAL EXCEPTION: main com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: android

im getting the FATAL EXCEPTION error in TypeAdapter.java file
here is TypeAdapter file
TypeAdapter file is locked to edit in android studio, so have to make changes in notepad, is the changes get update ?

```
public final class TypeAdapters {
  private TypeAdapters() {}

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public static final TypeAdapter<Class> CLASS = new TypeAdapter<Class>() {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Class value) throws IOException {
      if (value == null) {
        out.nullValue();
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: "
            + value.getName() + ". Forgot to register a type adapter?");
      }
    }
    @Override
    public Class read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?");
      }
    }
  };
  public static final TypeAdapterFactory CLASS_FACTORY = newFactory(Class.class, CLASS);

  public static final TypeAdapter<BitSet> BIT_SET = new TypeAdapter<BitSet>() {
    public BitSet read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }

      BitSet bitset = new BitSet();
      in.beginArray();
      int i = 0;
      JsonToken tokenType = in.peek();
      while (tokenType != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        boolean set;
        switch (tokenType) {
        case NUMBER:
          set = in.nextInt() != 0;
          break;
        case BOOLEAN:
          set = in.nextBoolean();
          break;
        case STRING:
          String stringValue = in.nextString();
          try {
            set = Integer.parseInt(stringValue) != 0;
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException(
                "Error: Expecting: bitset number value (1, 0), Found: " + stringValue);
          }
          break;
        default:
          throw new JsonSyntaxException("Invalid bitset value type: " + tokenType);
        }
        if (set) {
          bitset.set(i);
        }
        ++i;
        tokenType = in.peek();
      }
      in.endArray();
      return bitset;
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter out, BitSet src) throws IOException {
      if (src == null) {
        out.nullValue();
        return;
      }

      out.beginArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {
        int value = (src.get(i)) ? 1 : 0;
        out.value(value);
      }
      out.endArray();
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory BIT_SET_FACTORY = newFactory(BitSet.class, BIT_SET);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Boolean> BOOLEAN = new TypeAdapter<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      } else if (in.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
        // support strings for compatibility with GSON 1.7
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(in.nextString());
      }
      return in.nextBoolean();
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Boolean value) throws IOException {
      if (value == null) {
        out.nullValue();
        return;
      }
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Writes a boolean as a string. Useful for map keys, where booleans aren't
   * otherwise permitted.
   */
  public static final TypeAdapter<Boolean> BOOLEAN_AS_STRING = new TypeAdapter<Boolean>() {
    @Override public Boolean read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return Boolean.valueOf(in.nextString());
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, Boolean value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? "null" : value.toString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory BOOLEAN_FACTORY
      = newFactory(boolean.class, Boolean.class, BOOLEAN);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> BYTE = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        int intValue = in.nextInt();
        return (byte) intValue;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory BYTE_FACTORY
      = newFactory(byte.class, Byte.class, BYTE);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> SHORT = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return (short) in.nextInt();
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory SHORT_FACTORY
      = newFactory(short.class, Short.class, SHORT);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> INTEGER = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return in.nextInt();
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory INTEGER_FACTORY
      = newFactory(int.class, Integer.class, INTEGER);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> LONG = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return in.nextLong();
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> FLOAT = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return (float) in.nextDouble();
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> DOUBLE = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return in.nextDouble();
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> NUMBER = new TypeAdapter<Number>() {
    @Override
    public Number read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      JsonToken jsonToken = in.peek();
      switch (jsonToken) {
      case NULL:
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      case NUMBER:
        return new LazilyParsedNumber(in.nextString());
      default:
        throw new JsonSyntaxException("Expecting number, got: " + jsonToken);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Number value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory NUMBER_FACTORY = newFactory(Number.class, NUMBER);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Character> CHARACTER = new TypeAdapter<Character>() {
    @Override
    public Character read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      String str = in.nextString();
      if (str.length() != 1) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException("Expecting character, got: " + str);
      }
      return str.charAt(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Character value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : String.valueOf(value));
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory CHARACTER_FACTORY
      = newFactory(char.class, Character.class, CHARACTER);

  public static final TypeAdapter<String> STRING = new TypeAdapter<String>() {
    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      JsonToken peek = in.peek();
      if (peek == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      /* coerce booleans to strings for backwards compatibility */
      if (peek == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
        return Boolean.toString(in.nextBoolean());
      }
      return in.nextString();
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<BigDecimal> BIG_DECIMAL = new TypeAdapter<BigDecimal>() {
    @Override public BigDecimal read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return new BigDecimal(in.nextString());
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, BigDecimal value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<BigInteger> BIG_INTEGER = new TypeAdapter<BigInteger>() {
    @Override public BigInteger read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return new BigInteger(in.nextString());
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, BigInteger value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value);
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory STRING_FACTORY = newFactory(String.class, STRING);

  public static final TypeAdapter<StringBuilder> STRING_BUILDER = new TypeAdapter<StringBuilder>() {
    @Override
    public StringBuilder read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return new StringBuilder(in.nextString());
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, StringBuilder value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory STRING_BUILDER_FACTORY =
    newFactory(StringBuilder.class, STRING_BUILDER);

  public static final TypeAdapter<StringBuffer> STRING_BUFFER = new TypeAdapter<StringBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return new StringBuffer(in.nextString());
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, StringBuffer value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory STRING_BUFFER_FACTORY =
    newFactory(StringBuffer.class, STRING_BUFFER);

  public static final TypeAdapter<URL> URL = new TypeAdapter<URL>() {
    @Override
    public URL read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      String nextString = in.nextString();
      return "null".equals(nextString) ? null : new URL(nextString);
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, URL value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toExternalForm());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory URL_FACTORY = newFactory(URL.class, URL);

  public static final TypeAdapter<URI> URI = new TypeAdapter<URI>() {
    @Override
    public URI read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      try {
        String nextString = in.nextString();
        return "null".equals(nextString) ? null : new URI(nextString);
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new JsonIOException(e);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, URI value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toASCIIString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory URI_FACTORY = newFactory(URI.class, URI);

  public static final TypeAdapter<InetAddress> INET_ADDRESS = new TypeAdapter<InetAddress>() {
    @Override
    public InetAddress read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      // regrettably, this should have included both the host name and the host address
      return InetAddress.getByName(in.nextString());
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, InetAddress value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.getHostAddress());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory INET_ADDRESS_FACTORY =
    newTypeHierarchyFactory(InetAddress.class, INET_ADDRESS);

  public static final TypeAdapter<UUID> UUID = new TypeAdapter<UUID>() {
    @Override
    public UUID read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return java.util.UUID.fromString(in.nextString());
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, UUID value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory UUID_FACTORY = newFactory(UUID.class, UUID);

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory TIMESTAMP_FACTORY = new TypeAdapterFactory() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we use a runtime check to make sure the 'T's equal
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
      if (typeToken.getRawType() != Timestamp.class) {
        return null;
      }

      final TypeAdapter<Date> dateTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(Date.class);
      return (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<Timestamp>() {
        @Override public Timestamp read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
          Date date = dateTypeAdapter.read(in);
          return date != null ? new Timestamp(date.getTime()) : null;
        }

        @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, Timestamp value) throws IOException {
          dateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
        }
      };
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapter<Calendar> CALENDAR = new TypeAdapter<Calendar>() {
    private static final String YEAR = "year";
    private static final String MONTH = "month";
    private static final String DAY_OF_MONTH = "dayOfMonth";
    private static final String HOUR_OF_DAY = "hourOfDay";
    private static final String MINUTE = "minute";
    private static final String SECOND = "second";

    @Override
    public Calendar read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return  null;
      }
      in.beginObject();
      int year = 0;
      int month = 0;
      int dayOfMonth = 0;
      int hourOfDay = 0;
      int minute = 0;
      int second = 0;
      while (in.peek() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String name = in.nextName();
        int value = in.nextInt();
        if (YEAR.equals(name)) {
          year = value;
        } else if (MONTH.equals(name)) {
          month = value;
        } else if (DAY_OF_MONTH.equals(name)) {
          dayOfMonth = value;
        } else if (HOUR_OF_DAY.equals(name)) {
          hourOfDay = value;
        } else if (MINUTE.equals(name)) {
          minute = value;
        } else if (SECOND.equals(name)) {
          second = value;
        }
      }
      in.endObject();
      return new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay, minute, second);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Calendar value) throws IOException {
      if (value == null) {
        out.nullValue();
        return;
      }
      out.beginObject();
      out.name(YEAR);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      out.name(MONTH);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      out.name(DAY_OF_MONTH);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      out.name(HOUR_OF_DAY);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
      out.name(MINUTE);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
      out.name(SECOND);
      out.value(value.get(Calendar.SECOND));
      out.endObject();
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory CALENDAR_FACTORY =
    newFactoryForMultipleTypes(Calendar.class, GregorianCalendar.class, CALENDAR);

  public static final TypeAdapter<Locale> LOCALE = new TypeAdapter<Locale>() {
    @Override
    public Locale read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      String locale = in.nextString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(locale, "_");
      String language = null;
      String country = null;
      String variant = null;
      if (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        language = tokenizer.nextToken();
      }
      if (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        country = tokenizer.nextToken();
      }
      if (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        variant = tokenizer.nextToken();
      }
      if (country == null && variant == null) {
        return new Locale(language);
      } else if (variant == null) {
        return new Locale(language, country);
      } else {
        return new Locale(language, country, variant);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Locale value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : value.toString());
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory LOCALE_FACTORY = newFactory(Locale.class, LOCALE);

  public static final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> JSON_ELEMENT = new TypeAdapter<JsonElement>() {
    @Override public JsonElement read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      switch (in.peek()) {
      case STRING:
        return new JsonPrimitive(in.nextString());
      case NUMBER:
        String number = in.nextString();
        return new JsonPrimitive(new LazilyParsedNumber(number));
      case BOOLEAN:
        return new JsonPrimitive(in.nextBoolean());
      case NULL:
        in.nextNull();
        return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
      case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        in.beginArray();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
          array.add(read(in));
        }
        in.endArray();
        return array;
      case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
          object.add(in.nextName(), read(in));
        }
        in.endObject();
        return object;
      case END_DOCUMENT:
      case NAME:
      case END_OBJECT:
      case END_ARRAY:
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
    }

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, JsonElement value) throws IOException {
      if (value == null || value.isJsonNull()) {
        out.nullValue();
      } else if (value.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        JsonPrimitive primitive = value.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if (primitive.isNumber()) {
          out.value(primitive.getAsNumber());
        } else if (primitive.isBoolean()) {
          out.value(primitive.getAsBoolean());
        } else {
          out.value(primitive.getAsString());
        }

      } else if (value.isJsonArray()) {
        out.beginArray();
        for (JsonElement e : value.getAsJsonArray()) {
          write(out, e);
        }
        out.endArray();

      } else if (value.isJsonObject()) {
        out.beginObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : value.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
          out.name(e.getKey());
          write(out, e.getValue());
        }
        out.endObject();

      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't write " + value.getClass());
      }
    }
  };

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory JSON_ELEMENT_FACTORY
      = newTypeHierarchyFactory(JsonElement.class, JSON_ELEMENT);

  private static final class EnumTypeAdapter<T extends Enum<T>> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    private final Map<String, T> nameToConstant = new HashMap<String, T>();
    private final Map<T, String> constantToName = new HashMap<T, String>();

    public EnumTypeAdapter(Class<T> classOfT) {
      try {
        for (T constant : classOfT.getEnumConstants()) {
          String name = constant.name();
          SerializedName annotation = classOfT.getField(name).getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);
          if (annotation != null) {
            name = annotation.value();
          }
          nameToConstant.put(name, constant);
          constantToName.put(constant, name);
        }
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new AssertionError();
      }
    }
    public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return null;
      }
      return nameToConstant.get(in.nextString());
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
      out.value(value == null ? null : constantToName.get(value));
    }
  }

  public static final TypeAdapterFactory ENUM_FACTORY = newEnumTypeHierarchyFactory();

  public static TypeAdapterFactory newEnumTypeHierarchyFactory() {
    return new TypeAdapterFactory() {
      @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
      public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType) || rawType == Enum.class) {
          return null;
        }
        if (!rawType.isEnum()) {
          rawType = rawType.getSuperclass(); // handle anonymous subclasses
        }
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new EnumTypeAdapter(rawType);
      }
    };
  }



  public static <TT> TypeAdapterFactory newFactory(
      final Class<TT> unboxed, final Class<TT> boxed, final TypeAdapter<? super TT> typeAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapterFactory() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we use a runtime check to make sure the 'T's equal
      public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        return (rawType == unboxed || rawType == boxed) ? (TypeAdapter<T>) typeAdapter : null;
      }
      @Override public String toString() {
        return "Factory[type=" + boxed.getName()
            + "+" + unboxed.getName() + ",adapter=" + typeAdapter + "]";
      }
    };
  }

  public static <TT> TypeAdapterFactory newFactoryForMultipleTypes(final Class<TT> base,
      final Class<? extends TT> sub, final TypeAdapter<? super TT> typeAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapterFactory() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we use a runtime check to make sure the 'T's equal
      public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        Class<? super T> rawType = typeToken.getRawType();
        return (rawType == base || rawType == sub) ? (TypeAdapter<T>) typeAdapter : null;
      }
      @Override public String toString() {
        return "Factory[type=" + base.getName()
            + "+" + sub.getName() + ",adapter=" + typeAdapter + "]";
      }
    };
  }

  public static <TT> TypeAdapterFactory newTypeHierarchyFactory(
      final Class<TT> clazz, final TypeAdapter<TT> typeAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapterFactory() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ? (TypeAdapter<T>) typeAdapter : null;
      }
      @Override public String toString() {
        return "Factory[typeHierarchy=" + clazz.getName() + ",adapter=" + typeAdapter + "]";
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Error log

```
06-27 11:46:57.888 3370-3370/com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:241)
                                                                                   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231)
```

Comment: No, as soon as you build the project , the changes will get lost. Please post out your class file in which this exception occured.

Comment: TypeAdapter.java which i already posted, error shown at  public static final TypeAdapter<Number> INTEGER = new TypeAdapter<Number>()

Comment: Please post out error log.

Comment: TypeAdapter class is in a GSON Package so we can't make any changes to this class. Actually, GSON was expecting a double value and your response   contains a String.

Comment: post the error log

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am getting the same error

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky check your bean class aka model class and check data type